# Is it still possible to get 'NullPointerException' on property 'x' when building an Object from a result of a query with 'Where x is not null'

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I am using exposed in one project, and I have a table lets call it `TableX` with two properties
`property1` and `x` knowing that `x` is nullable
I added `TableX.x.isNotNull()` to my query so I can ignore null rows!.

And I have `Object1` with also two properties as `TableX` which are: `property1` and `x` knowing that `x` is not null in Object1

Then when I create Object1 out of the rows from the query, the compiler will nag about `x` because it should not be null and we are receiving a nullable x from TableX.

So I have added `!!` when setting `x` in Object1, given that I am sure that the query will never return any row with `x is null` because of the constraint that I have added.

But still, I receive `KotlinNullPointerException` some times. So how is this possible?

I thought of some compatibility issues between `MySQL` and `exposed`! But couldn't find any

```
   val result = listOf<Object1>()

   transaction {
        val query = TableX.select {
            TableX.property1.eq(123) and
            TableX.x.isNotNull()
        }
            .fetchSize(1000)

        result = query.map {
            Object1(
                property1 = it[TableX.property1],
                x = it[TableX.x]!!
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: What database do you use? Could you ensure (by adding SQLLogger) that executed query have only `property1 = 123 and x is not null` in a where part?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem in a company I am working now. And it looks like you have race condition in place. Try to explicitly check for `null` before building result list. At least you won't get an exception.

Comment: Thank you for your response :). But the thing is adding 'where x is not null' supposed to be the `if` that I am relying on. And race condition should note occur here because of the transaction, what do you think?